# Vertical space between inline-block elements smaller than font

Tags: html, css

First, I know about the letter-spacing problem that causes horizontal spaces between inline-block elements. This is not another of those questions.

Instead, I have a full-width inline-block element with a small height, and I want its next neighbor to abut it directly from below, but there's always a space between them that looks to be about the line-height.

I've tried every combination of vertical-align, font-size, and line-height I can think of. Anyone have a creative way of removing that whitespace?

```css
.blue{background:blue;}
.red{background:red;}

.blue,.red{
  width: 100%;
  height:5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Why is this happening?

The `font-size` of the parent element, in this case `body`, affects the `inline-block` divs, essentially treating them like text.

#### How can we keep the elements `inline-block` with no white space?

The parent element, `body` in this example, is given `font-size: 0`, you would then give the child elements a `font-size`:

```css
body {
font-size: 0;
}
.blue{background:blue;}
.red{background:red;}

.blue,.red{
  width: 100%;
  height:5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
```

#### Should we do this?

I can't think of a practical use of this, use `display: block`.

Comment: One reason to use `inline-block` is so you don't have to clear-fix. Too bad it introduces a new headache.

Comment: Wow! After hours searching in Internet. finally I've found the mistery behind spurious vertical spacing, even in HR tags, with no text.

Answer (score 2):

Float them?

```css
.blue{background:blue;}
.red{background:red;}

.blue,.red{
  width: 100%;
  height:5px;
  display: inline-block;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use 100% width, then why not use `display: block` instead of inline-block.

Note:
If you want to use float, its a good practice to clear it after.
while using float, display property is not required as Float takes care of it.

```css
.blue{background:blue;}
.red{background:red;}

.blue,.red{
  height:5px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
```

Comment: I answered with block/flex/table and deleted it, but he wanted it with inline-block :)